# Remove Field Name from Pop Up Label in ArcGIS Online

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online

I am trying to remove the field name in the pop up label in one of my map layers in ArcGIS Online in order to simplify the label.

In the below example, I don't want to show the words: Name, Address, ST_DIR, etc.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I3U6.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Configure Pop-ups" tool in the layer menu.  After it opens you may choose "custom attribute display" in the Display pulldown.  Then, hit the "Configure" button.

Read about this feature here: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm